# Ubuntu VLAN configuration problems

Tags: networking, netplan, vlan

I've an Ubuntu box that is directly connecting to a port of firewall appliance running OPNSense. This port is running a DHCP on VLAN (say 10) and I need to configure the Ubuntu box to connect to it.

I tried several combination of code in Ubuntu's /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
  version: 2
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: eno1
      dhcp4: yes
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.1
```

But executing "netplan try" command always gives an error :

```
/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml:3:10: Error in network definition: expected mapping (check indentation) eno1:
```

I'm not sure what I need to write for "eno1" as I do not want any untagged interface on this port.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: That's a pretty garbled bit of yaml.  I'd suggest looking at https://netplan.io/examples for what the netplan yaml defs look like; there are some specific examples for connecting to a VLAN.

Comment: My bad, the first line got indented out but I've fixed it and the code should read fine now. The examples in netplan do not give any instance where the interface is "tagged" only running on VLAN specific DHCP.

Comment: Looks like yaml doesn't like the eno1: label with no contents. I put "optional: true" there and netplan try would take it.  Don't have a VLAN capable switch so I couldn't test if it actually worked.

Comment: I don't know how to ensure there's no untagged interface; what I'd try is dhcp4: no and set no addresses, then at least nothing should be sent through the bare interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RFM, adding "dhcp4: no" did the trick and VLAN is working now!

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
  version: 2
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: eno1
      dhcp4: yes
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.10.1
```